# Handling backreferences in re.sub when replacement includes numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regexp-replace

Take the following simple regex replacement:

```py
import re
s = "Python version is: 3.10"
pat = r'(is:.*)\d+\.\d+$'
version = "3.12"
result = re.sub(pat, rf'\1{version}', s)
print(result)
```

This fails with:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    raise s.error("invalid group reference %d" % index, pos)
re.error: invalid group reference 13 at position 1
```

What is happening is that the raw string interprets the backreference and includes the first "3" of the version string as its reference.

I've tried various iterations of:

```
re.sub(pat, rf'\1{version}', s)
re.sub(pat, f'\\1{version}', s)
re.sub(pat, r'\1' + version, s)
re.sub(pat, r'\1{0}'.format(version), s)
re.sub(pat, r'\1' + f"{version}", s)
```

But none will treat the string part as an actual string. Am I stuck using a named capture group for this?

Answer (score 1):

Python's `re.sub` accepts a *[group](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub:%7E:text=%5Cg%3Cquote%3E-,%5Cg%3C1%3E,-%5C1)* indicator that you can use for both numbered and named capture groups:

```py
import re
s = "Python version is: 3.10"
pat = r'(is:.*)\d+\.\d+$'
version = "3.12"
result = re.sub(pat, rf'\g<1>{version}', s)
print(result)
```

```py
import re
s = "Python version is: 3.10"
pat = r'(?P<keep>is:.*)\d+\.\d+$'
version = "3.12"
result = re.sub(pat, rf'\g<keep>{version}', s)
print(result)
```